# Laravel log in as does not work on production server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

The platform I'm maintaining has a feature where users that are in the same company object can login as other users in their company.

I'm having an issue where calling Auth::login($user) does not seem to be working, but I cannot reproduce the error on my local or staging server. I can log every step along the way and it seems to be working. But after I call my redirect, it appears to log you out.

Testing on my local machine results in the code working perfectly! This only seems to be an issue on my production server.

Any ideas are *greatly* appreciated!

```
  public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('can:access_admin')
         ->except(['logOutOfUser', 'logInAsUser']);
}

public function logInAsUser(Request $request)
{

    $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    if (! $user) {
        abort('404', 'User does not exist');
    }

    if ($user->id == Auth::id()) {
        abort('404', 'You can\'t log in as yourself!');
    }

    if (! Auth::user()->canLogInAs($user)) {
        abort('404', 'You don\'t have access to that user!');
    }


    $admin = Auth::user();
    Log::debug("1",Session::all());
    Session::put('admin_logged_in_as', $admin);
    Log::debug("2",Session::all());
    Auth::login($user);
    Log::debug("3",Session::all());
    Log::debug('4',Auth::user()->toArray());
    return redirect('/dashboard/listings');
}
```

https://i.postimg.cc/bNCgzgpY/sanity.png

Comment: First things that come to mind from experience with logins/sessions on local vs production are different session drivers on your local vs production, multiple production instances (load-balancer), etc. You might need to provide a bit more information on how your production environment is set differently than your local.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I Should have included that information. The session drivers are defined in my .env file.
Locally the SESSION_DRIVER=file
QA and PROD the SESSION_DRIVER=database